# Bash command mysql : escape single quote from variable

Tags: mysql, bash, variables, escaping

This command

```
echo "mysql -u root nextcloud -Bse 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path=\""${FILE_PATH}"\";'"
```

will show that

```
mysql -u root nextcloud -Bse 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="files_encryption/keys/files/xxx/xxxx/xxx L'AME/2xxxx/OC_DEFAULT_MODULE/master_x626.shareKey";'
```

There is a single quote in the path. When i execute command, this does not work. When script execute this commande

```
mysql -u root nextcloud -Bse 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="${FILE_PATH}";'
```

It does not work too. Row is not deleted.
From HeidySQL this command work, row is deleted.

```
DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="files_encryption/keys/files/xxx/xxxx/xxx L'AME/2xxxx/OC_DEFAULT_MODULE/master_x626.shareKey";
```

What should i do to escape single quote from variable throught mysql -Bse? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the single quote in the string stored in the variable, it's that you're single-quoting the whole string that includes that variable so the shell can't expand it. Instead of:

```
mysql ... 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="${FILE_PATH}";'
```

try:

```
mysql ... "DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path=\"${FILE_PATH}\";"
```

or similar and if that's not all you need, try something else where `$FILE_PATH` isn't inside a string delimited by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mysql -u root nextcloud -Bse 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="files_encryption/keys/files/xxx/xxxx/xxx L'\''AME/2xxxx/OC_DEFAULT_MODULE/master_x626.shareKey";'
```

The first `'` close the command, `\'` escape single quote out of the whole query, and the last ' concats the rest of the command.

Comment: I can't. path is a variable. Here I have indicated the value of the variable for example.

Comment: I have tested but this does not work, quote is not escaped

Comment: In my locale its working fine, can you share the error you got ? maybe you can test with a simple select as well

Comment: [root@xxx ~]# mysql -u root nextcloud -Bse 'DELETE FROM oc_filecache WHERE path="files_encryption/keys/files/XXXX/XXXX/XX_INTERFACE L\'AME/XXX-5110-01.pdf/OC_DEFAULT_MODULE/master_7c357626.shareKey";'
>          This is like a single quote is missing, bash is waiting.